# How to simulate pressing the arrow down key when a specific element is present in the HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, keyboard, arrow-keys

I want python to click on a key on my keyboard for example the arrow down key when a specific word for example google is present somewhere in the browser or in the searh bar. Is it possible with selenium or the os module. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to click on the <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> key when a specific condition is met, as an example I have demonstrated through the following steps:

- Open the url https://www.google.com/
- Wait for the *Google Home Page search box* element i.e. `By.NAME, "q"` to be clickable.
- Sends the character sequence **selenium**.
- Wait for the auto suggestions to be visibile.
- Click **twice** on <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> key.

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("Selenium")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[role='listbox'] li")))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    ```
  - Browser Snapshot:

[image: Keys.DOWN]

> PS: Implementing the above logic you can also click on <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> and <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 1):

you could search for the element with an xpath looking for the text you are searching e.g. `$x('//*[.="Text"]')` and then use `sendKey()` to press the key